# Why do I have to do ldarg.0 before calling a field in MSIL?

Tags: field, cil

I want to call a function, with as parameters a `string` and an `Int32`. The `string` is just a literal, the `Int32` should be a `field`. So I thought it should be something like:

```
.method public hidebysig instance string TestVoid() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] string CS$1$0000)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldstr "myString"
    L_0006: ldfld int32 FirstNamespace.FirstClass::ByteField
    L_000b: call string [Class1]Class1.TestClass::Functie<int32>(string, int32)
    L_0010: ret 
}
```

But this throws the error that this is not valid code. When adding

```
ldarg.0
```

before `ldfld` it runs just fine. Why is this, and is this going to get me into trouble when having more fields?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Instance methods have an implicit parameter called "this". It is loaded as the first argument to the stack, thus you have ldarg.0 for "this".

Comment: doesn't ldarg.0 correspond to the first parameter passed to a method ?

Comment: As Joel Marcey explains, there is an implicit first parameter "this".  A bit like when you declare an extension method and include parameter (this targetType  targetObject, ... which you then later do not have to reference.

Comment: ... e.g. You can have a method: public static char MyStringMethod(this String inputString, int index) { return inputString[index]; } - when you call it, the first parameter is implicit - var myCharacter = myString.MyStringMethod(5); - but is still loaded when the method is executed.