# MSIL code for accessing a readonly field results in ldarg.0

Tags: c#, .net, cil

I have a simple method in C# that accesses a readonly field:

```
IL_0024:  ldarg.0
IL_0025:  ldfld      string MyAssembly.MyClass.TestClass::A
```

My natural assumption was that this is used for loading the "this" reference when accessing member fields, and this question also confirms that: [Why do I have to do ldarg.0 before calling a field in MSIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785372/why-do-i-have-to-do-ldarg-0-before-calling-a-field-in-msil)

However, the documentation for [ldarg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldarg_0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) mentions that it is used for loading parameters passed to the method.

What is the correct explanation for this behaviour? and how can one distinguish between loading the "this" reference and loading the first formal parameter to a method in IL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are correct :)

The `this` value is passed as a first "invisible" parameter to instance methods, so in an instance method, `ldarg.0` is "load the `this` value".

You can see the difference if you write a method which uses a *different* parameter. For example:

```
static void StaticMethod(int x)
{
    // This uses ldarg.0
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}

void InstanceMethod(int x)
{
    // This uses ldarg.1
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

> and how can one distinguish between loading the "this" reference and loading the first formal parameter to a method in IL?

By checking the above, basically - if it's an instance method, then `ldarg.0` loads the implicit `this` value. Otherwise, it loads the first formal parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

All instance methods takes first parameter as the class instance itself. This is done implicitly, so you don't have to pass it when you're calling a method.

Given that `this` is a method parameter, you need to use `ldarg.0` to push the `this` instance to evaluation stack.